# How to convert c++ class to managed class?

Tags: c#, c++, clr

I want to change the c++ class to c# managed class using the method in this url:https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/inheriting-from-a-native-c-class-in-c/
but it can not work in the constructor.
the class like this:

```cpp
 class memoryTest
        {
          public:
          std::shared_ptr<void> object_ptr;
          std::deque<std::vector<int>> prev_vec_deque;
          std::string _cfg, _weight;
          int cur_id;
          float nms;
          bool wait_stream;

       };
```

to:[c# managed class]

```cs
 public unsafe struct __CClass
       {

        //IntPtr* _vtable;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 0x2)]
        IntPtr[] shared_ptr_0;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 0x5)]
        List<bbox_t[]> tracking_id;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x28)]
        public byte[] portText1;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x28)]
        public byte[] portText2;
        int cur_id;
        float nms;
        bool wait_stream;
      };
```

I have see the X64asm code,and using pointer to hold the space, and then construct, the c++ function can alloc struct in it, but something wrong.
what's the trouble is that: how to convert the deque and shared_ptr?

```
_cpp = (__CClass*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal((IntPtr)(sizeof(__CClass) ));
RtlZeroMemory((IntPtr)_cpp, (UIntPtr)sizeof(__CClass));           
//Call constructor _CClass_Constructor(_cpp, configurationFilename, weightsFilename, 0, 1);
```

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException:“Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Pointers cannot reference marshaled structures.  Use ByRef instead.”

Comment: Learn about C++/cli, but I would not use inheritance at all but aggregation (inheritance is over-used as it is already). This is the simplest primer I know : [Quick C++/CLI - Learn C++/CLI in less than 10 minutes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes)

Comment: These std::xxx things are also classes, you need convert them first.

Comment: You can't use `std::` in C# at all, it doesn't know how to marshal them

Comment: This sound like a horrible idea. There are ways to deal with interop between c# and c++, but they tend to be complex and problematic in the best of cases. If the class is small it is probably better to just rewrite it in c#.

Comment: thanks for yours answers. I already know how to do it. two ways(c++ and clr) 1. write an manage wrapper class  2. write an c++ DLL and wrap the class to a simple class which can easy convert to c#  .  All of the above require writing a wrapper DLL for it. hope this can help others.